# A bijection from a disconnected space to a connected space?

Tags: general-topology

Can we find an bijective continuous map $f:X\to Y$ from a disconnected topological space $X$ to a connected topological space $Y$?

It seems counter intuitive for me, but I am not able to prove that $f(X)$ will be disconnected. I cannot think of any counterexample either. Can someone help?

Answer (score 6):

Take the interval $[0,1)$ disjoint union with $[2,3]$ mapping in the obvious way to $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=Y=\{0,1\}$. Give $X$ the discrete topology and give $Y$ the indiscrete topology.  The identity function from $X$ to $Y$ is a continuous bijection, $X$ is not connected, and $Y$ is connected.